# Android library for lossless JPEG transformation (rotate/crop/join)

Tags: android, open-source, library, jpg, lossless

[jpegtran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg#jpegtran) allows to **rotate**/**crop**/**join** a JPG file without any quality loss nor file size increase.

Is there a Java or Kotlin **library** to achieve these lossless operations in **Android**?

Non-solutions:

- [libjpeg-turbo](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo/issues/71#issuecomment-1089926240)'s Java library is almost perfect but unfortunately it does not implement the join (called `-drop`) operation, even though the C library of the same project does. Probably the easiest to port if necessary.
- [AndroidMediaUtil](https://github.com/bkhall/AndroidMediaUtil/issues/4) and [LLCrop](https://github.com/k3b/LosslessJpgCrop/issues/33) also do not support join.
- [maven-jpegtran-plugin](https://github.com/simonox/maven-jpegtran-plugin) calls the `jpegtran` OS executable, so it is not 100% Java.
- [Android's source code includes `jpegtran.c`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:external/libjpeg-turbo/jpegtran.c) but I have not found any way for an app to call it, I guess it is only used internally, maybe only present because it is a part of libjpeg.

Must be open source.
Libraries that only do one operation, for instance only crop, are very welcome too!

Answer (score 0):

[LLCrop is open source](https://github.com/k3b/LosslessJpgCrop). I hope this helps!

Comment: It does not support the join operation, right? LLCrop uses the Spectrum library, which uses mozjpeg, which is a patch over libjpeg-turbo, whose Java version does not have join.